# Eclipse Juno and android maven plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I'm having alot of pain getting some of my android projects to run on eclipse 4.2, they run fine in Indigo , but not so much in Juno.

I'm using the android maven plugin, and they also runs fine from the console, using

```
mvn android:run
```

But after importing the projects into Juno, I get the following errors

```
An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
com/android/io/StreamException
```

and

```
WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /path-to-project-bin/jarlist.cache
```

Then when trying to run the project, I get the following error in the console

```
R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

and the application crash on startup.

Have anybody seen similar problems with Juno?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with the [m2e-android connector](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android) caused by the update for ADT version 20.0.0 that is being worked on:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/89

---

**Update**: The new 0.4.2 release fixes this issue was released today, please run an Eclipse update (Help -> Check for Updates) and let me know if this resolves your problems.