# "Mavenising" ActionBarSherlock Library

Tags: android, maven

This is a continuation of this problem: [ActionBarSherlock + maven + eclipse: dependency not found in workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043237/actionbarsherlock-maven-eclipse-dependency-not-found-in-workspace)

I was getting the error:

```
dependency=[com.actionbarsherlock:library:apklib:4.1.0:compile] not found in workspace
```

I downloaded the ActionBarSherlock code and added it to my workspace.

However, when I try to build my own project, I'm getting the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: 
Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
```

I believe this is because the duplicate jar being generated. I think it's because the v4 support library appears on both my project & the ActionBarSherlock library.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Android libraries is still in development for m2e-android:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/8

The problems you're having with the ActionBarSherlock library are known issues which we hope to fix in the near future:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/104

Comment: Is there at least a workaround for this issue? I've spent several *hours* trying to get RedReader (which uses HoloEverywhere, which in turn uses ActionBarSherlock) to build in Eclipse with no success. Those two links have 2 years worth of discussion, so it's very hard to tell if a solution is buried somewhere in there.