# actionbarsherlock samples + Maven

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, adt

I have imported the actionbarsherlock to Eclipse and I'm trying to build the samples. All Eclipse plugins are up-to-date. I took the original pom.xml but changed the Android API version to 23.

However in each sample I encounter the following message:

```
dependency=[com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:apklib:4.4.0:compile] not found in workspace
```

Whatis wrong with the combination Maven/Eclipse/Sherlock apklib? The apklib was downloaded properly in the local Maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found this answer.

[ActionBarSherlock + maven + eclipse: dependency not found in workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043237/actionbarsherlock-maven-eclipse-dependency-not-found-in-workspace?rq=1)

However the answer-link is not valid any more (http 404).